# Opening an Oracle database with a corrupted redo log

Tags: oracle

I have a database that is not open. And I have a redo log that is corrupted.

What would be the best way for me to open the database? This is a testing db and I am not concerned with data loss - but I need to get the database open and working again.

Some additional notes:
Trying to switch logs tells me that the log is required for recovery
Attempting to recover fails
Trying to open gives the error msg that the log is corrupted

Additional clarification:
I do need some of the data in the db; but I don't need any of the recent data (about a year worth of data). There is some configuration data which I do want.
I don't know the structure of the db, and I have no script to re-create it.

Comment: I should be more clear - 1) I am not concerned about recent data - about all the data from the last year or so, 2) I actually don't know the structure of the database

Comment: Do you have a backup of the database?  Can you restore that backup?

Comment: no, unfortunately not

Comment: If you have no backup of the database and have no other source for the data, I would **strongly** recommend first that you back up whatever you have so that you are absolutely certain that you can get back to the current state.  And then I would recommend getting someone to look at the problem and figure out how best to move forward rather than trying trying out suggestions from the internet.  Very few of the things that you might try are reversible and there are generally lots (and lots) of questions that would need to be answered before proceeding.

Comment: There are ways how to bypass media recovery phase, and open an inconsistent database.  But this is beyond SO questions. You should contact Oracle support.

Comment: [Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/int_allow_resetlogs_corruption.htm) describes a similar situation, but you should follow the advice of @Justin.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is to clear the redo log.

```
ALTER DATABASE CLEAR LOGFILE GROUP #;
```